# Semantic roles of 'direct object'

Tags: direct-objects, grammatical-roles

What are the primary semantic roles of 'direct object'? In particular, I was wondering what the semantic roles of 'direct object' are in such sentences as:

> They crossed **the river**.
> He promised her that he would do **it**.
> He did not mention **the matter** at all.
> She left **her room**.
> He would say **nothing**.
> They ate **the pie**.

Comment: In *He promised her that he would do it*, **her** is an indirect object and a complement. In *She left her room*,I suspect *her room* is a complement. The primary (commonest) role of the direct object is to be the NP upon which the verb operates.

Comment: Your *promised* example is wrong. There the clause is the direct object, the pronoun the **indirect** object. See [the OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/152433).  In two-object constructions like these, it says that the indirect object is “Usually to the benefit or advantage of the person concerned”, which is a standard Beneficiary semantic role and normal in indirect objects.

Comment: @tchrist: That construction is perfectly normal, and there’s an example on that *OED* page at **1. c.** With clause as object, expressing the act promised: 2001 / N. H. WILSON *Mountain Pose* i. 6 / What homework did she have? She’d have to get it done, because she’d promised Dad that yoga class wouldn’t interfere.

Comment: @TinfoilHat Yes, I initially actually referred to its sense **1. c.** in my comment but shortened it. Thanks for adding that.

Comment: @tchrist: Ah, I see — you were objecting to the OP’s highlighting of *her* as a direct object?

Comment: @TinfoilHat Right.

Answer (score 1):

The semantic roles of direct objects are completely dependent on the verbs they are objects of.

When you look at the details, practically every verb with any specificity in meaning (i.e, not a small verb like *put, get,* or *make*) has a uniquely limited set of noun types that it can take as object.  You can water the plants and the lawn, but not the dog or the children, for instance, though the meaning would be clear.

Indirect objects are almost always receivers (there are verbs like *elect* with two objects that aren't describing transit, but they're rare), and human receivers at that. But direct objects are, in a sense, part of the verb -- certainly part of the verb phrase -- and the limitations and requirements set by transitive predicates for their direct objects are part of their meaning.

For instance, we have dozens of verbs for talking, including *say* and *tell*. Why so many? What's the difference? Lots. *Say* can take a direct quote, even in a foreign language, but *tell* can't

- *He said "Arma virumque cano" to her.*
- *She said "I don't speak Latin" to him.*
- *She told him she didn't speak Latin*
- **She told him "I don't speak Latin"*
- **She told him "Non loquor Latine"*

*Tell*, but not *say,* requires an indirect object

- *I said to her that it was 5:00.*
- *I said that it was 5:00.*
- *I told him what time it was.*
- **I told what time it was*

... and so on. The details are always different.

Comment: I would say that in "I told him what time it was", "him" is direct (not indirect) object of "told", and "what time it was" is a subordinate interrogative clause functioning as second complement of "told". And in "She said "I don't speak Latin" to him", the direct reported speech is not direct object of "speak" but complement.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware that you prefer different terminology. And "indirect object" can refer to either of the variants of the dative alternation. In a derivational description, node labels assigned to intermediate stages are really quite irrelevant.

Comment: The usual rule is that if there's only one object in a clause, it's a direct one. Since "what time it was" is an interrogative clause complement not an object, that means that "him" must be direct object.

Comment: _Since_ presupposes its clause. In derivational theories, interrogative clause complements can be noun phrases and objects, so adopting your usual terminology would serve no purpose except to display incorrect tribal markings.

Comment: It's not my terminology. It is of course based on H&P's CGEL, so one could hardly call it incorrect! I agree entirely with Huddleston when he says that the classification of finite subordinate clauses should be based on their internal form rather than spurious analogies with the parts of speech. "What time it was" thus belongs to the category interrogative 'clause' -- to claim otherwise would be perverse.

Comment: It's a theory. It makes assumptions. It presupposes things. It's yours, and you can use it as you please, like any theory. So can I.

Answer (score -1):

It depends on which system of thematic roles you use. All of them are Themes. However, there are more types of Themes.